# One variable name with multiple attribution

Tags: c, attributes

I want to write an function which reads specific sensor values from a modbus device.
To read the sensor value I need the device address and the register number.
I need an solution to store this two attribution under one name.
Example:

```
TEMPSENSOR_1 = deviceAddress = 0x09, registerNum = 0 
sensorRead(TEMPSENSOR_1){ 
get the two attribution by name
modbusRequest(deviceAddress, registerNum ....);
}
```

When I am make an modbusRequest need the deviceAddress and registerNum from as name TEMPSENSOR_1.

How can I do this?

Comment: Why do you think you need to store these two different attributes as a single variable?

Comment: I don't understand... Do you need  such `struct` or `pair` to be used by something ?

Comment: I write an universal function wich read the specific sensor value:
void sesorRead(sensorName)
{
....
mosbudReuest(deviceAddress,registerNum....)
}

Comment: Please pick one language. C and C++ are actually different languages and the code to address your problem may or may not be same for both.

Comment: C or C++? custom struct, std::pair, ...

Comment: Ok, and your question is related to the parameter of `sensorRead` ?

Comment: Please, edit your post to be more precise.

Comment: I want an solution to store two attribution in one name. In sensorRead function I need the two attribution by name.

Comment: Beyond structures (or in C++ classes) there no way to store multiple "attributes" in a single name. And it's not really a true multi-attribute variable, since you still have two member *variables* inside the structure. And if you need to pass the two attributes as separate arguments to you `modbusRequest` function, why not use two different variables to begin with? So in short: It's not possible, and you still haven't told us *why* you need it.

Comment: I think using structure is a good solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your code is written in C++ (**not in C**) :

I think you need to use  a `std::pair` from the header `<utility>` to do that.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair

This allow you to store two values in the same object. But please make sure that these two values are strongly related to each other. If it's not, do not use that, and refactor your code.

---

If your code is written in C :

I think you want to use a `struct` who store two values.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_structures.htm

This allow you to store two values in the same object. But please make sure that these two values are strongly related to each other. If it's not, do not use that, and refactor your code.

Do you need more informations ?